# find the minimum pair in given list

Tags: c#

let we have a list of int array [{0,1},{1,2},{4,5}] who are friends in pair
how can we find the friends who are friend of other pairs to. the list of friend will be (0,1,2) and (4,5) and print it in c#.
If the number exist in pair of int array then it will be added in, and printed in C#
e.g; list have [{0,1},{1,2},{4,5}]
then possible print will be (0,1,2) and (4,5)

***lets 0,1 are friends, 1,2 are friends, and 4,5 are friends, then 0,1,2 are friend and 4,5 are friends***

Comment: You'll get a better response if you show us what you've tried already.

Comment: The values posted do not make any sense.

Comment: i have passed the list of array in function like: new int[3, 2] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
and try to find the pairs

Comment: I'm sorry, what does _"If the number exist in pair of int array then it will be added in"_ mean?

Comment: i have tried to edit the question and explained it as a friend. please forgive for the bad english.

Comment: Can you add more examples or intput output

Comment: @aloisdg lets 0,1 are friends, 1,2 are friends, and 4,5 are friends, then (0,1,2) will be printed and friend (4,5) are friends will be printed

Comment: This is exactly the same example...

Comment: Don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve here but if you are trying to find common elements across arrays this link might be able to get you started : [find common element in array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100371/find-the-common-element-in-two-int-arrays)

Comment: Ah, I think this question is asking about how to find cycles. Here {0,1} and {1,2} combine to form {0,1,2}.

Comment: @BurnsBA yeah I'm pretty sure that's what it is. Just posted my answer... Had one posted already but I wrote it in Java at first.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for what you need?

```
List<int[]> pairsOfFriends = new List<int[]>
{
    new int[] {0, 1},
    new int[] {1, 2},
    new int[] {4, 5},
};
Dictionary<int, List<int>> friendsLists = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
pairsOfFriends.ForEach(pairOfFriends =>
{
    int friendA = pairOfFriends[0];
    int friendB = pairOfFriends[1];
    //if friendA has a friends list, then friendA wants to share his friends list with friendB!
    if (friendsLists.ContainsKey(friendA))
    {
        var friendsListA = friendsLists[friendA];
        //if friendB has a friend list, they also want to share all of their friends with friendA.
        if (friendsLists.ContainsKey(friendB))
        {
            //friendA copies all of friendB's friends into his own friends list
            friendsListA.AddRange(friendsLists[friendB]);
            //friendB and friendA then share friendA's friends list so that they share the same friends!
            friendsLists[friendB].ForEach(friendBsFriend =>
            {
                friendsLists.Remove(friendBsFriend);
                friendsLists.Add(friendBsFriend,friendsListA);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //if friendB doesn't have any friends, then friendA shares all of his friends with friendB and then adds friendB to his own friends list
            friendsLists.Add(friendB, friendsListA);
            friendsListA.Add(friendB);
        }
        //if friendB has a friends list, and friendA doesnt then friendB adds friendA to his friends list and then shares his friends list with friendA.
    }
    else if (friendsLists.ContainsKey(friendB))
    {
        var friendsListB = friendsLists[friendB];
        friendsLists.Add(friendA, friendsListB);
        friendsListB.Add(friendA);
    }
    //if neither friendB or friendA have a friends list then friend a makes a new friends list, adds himself and friendB to it and then shares the friends list with friend B
    else
    {
        friendsLists.Add(friendA, new List<int> {friendA, friendB});
        friendsLists.Add(friendB, friendsLists[friendA]);
    }
});
friendsLists.Values.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(f =>
{
    Console.Write("("+string.Join(", ", f)+") ");
});
```